# How to add labels to OpenTelemetry C++ metrics

Tags: c++, tags, label, metrics, open-telemetry

I am working with the OpenTelemetry C++ [metric_simple](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp/tree/main/examples/metrics_simple) example & looking to understand how to add metric labels.

I saw in the [main.cc](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp/blob/3a8f913de52c19868e2d325cc17b5d62e0d4fd4e/examples/metrics_simple/main.cc#L40) file, there are instances of:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> labels = {{"key", "value"}};
   auto labelkv = common::KeyValueIterableView<decltype(labels)>{labels};
```

However, I am not sure how to go about adding key:value labels to metrics. Has anyone had success with this in the past?

Answer (score 1):

The example is located in the [`foo_library`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp/blob/main/examples/common/metrics_foo_library/foo_library.cc):

```cpp
  std::string histogram_name                  = name + "_histogram";
  auto provider                               = metrics_api::Provider::GetMeterProvider();
  nostd::shared_ptr<metrics_api::Meter> meter = provider->GetMeter(name, "1.2.0");
  auto histogram_counter                      = meter->CreateDoubleHistogram(histogram_name);
  auto context                                = opentelemetry::context::Context{};
  while (true)
  {
    double val                                = (rand() % 700) + 1.1;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> labels = get_random_attr();
    auto labelkv = opentelemetry::common::KeyValueIterableView<decltype(labels)>{labels};
    histogram_counter->Record(val, labelkv, context);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
  }
```